# disable listview scrolling when ontouchlistener is fired

Tags: android, android-listview, ontouchlistener

i attached a ontouch listener to my listview so i can drag the listview left to right. While im dragging the listview im able to scroll it as well. How can i disable the listview scroll while i'm dragging it.

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true; // Indicates that this has been handled by you and will not be forwarded further.
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**OR**

```
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```